# Sub module output file name after building with Angular CLI `build --prod`

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-module

After running the build command with Angular CLI:
`ng b --prod --aot=true`

The files created are:

```
chunk {0} runtime.357e94d34f7942763d58.js (runtime) 2.18 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.a8f5e4902af4bd8aa72b.js (main) 1020 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.6907d08705301f0819db.js (polyfills) 187 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.56ccbf199ac1e484578a.js (polyfills-es5) 70 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.6c6ae7ea60d55e8f9770.css (styles) 2.23 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.31277aaf6373f44b242f.js () 115 kB  [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.abed933ee3bd36293b18.js (scripts) 474 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2019-11-20T11:25:23.058Z - Hash: e4e168e707e94e5393d7 - Time: 20639ms
```

Please note the {5} file `chunk {5} 5.31277aaf6373f44b242f.js () 115 kB  [rendered]` , this is the file created for sub module that i have inside my main angular project.
how can i control the **file name** of this output file?

folders/files tree of my project:

```
-- src
   -- app
      -- ** project files
      -- my-sub-module-directory
         -- ** sub module files, include submodule.ts file
```

Comment: I read the formal docs at [cli build docx](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) and also [Angular.io](https://cli.angular.io/) cli page, didnt find my answer

Comment: --namedChunks=true

Comment: why do you want to control the name can you specify ? cause there are drawbacks of using he same name again and again ( cache issues)

Comment: I think you have to change the current Webpack configuration. To do that inside Angular it's a bit tricky because it is encapsulated under the hood.
You can find some guides here:
https://netbasal.com/customize-webpack-configuration-in-your-angular-application-d09683f6bd22
And then you can try to change the chunk configuration as described in the Webpack documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: @JBNizet it look like this is taking me one step closer to the desired answer. now i'm getting some long filename `xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-module-ngfactory.057d32838645035340d4.js`. i'll keep research from this point. thanks.